# Dealing with git permission errors on root mounted partition

Tags: permissions, git

I am trying to clone a git repository from my home directory to a cifs partition, but I keep getting this file permission error.

```
[cguest@devserver groupmount]$ pwd
/mnt/groupmount

[cguest@devserver groupmount]$ mkdir util_scripts/
[cguest@devserver groupmount]$ git clone /home/cguest/repositories/util_scripts
Initialized empty Git repository in /mnt/groupmount/util_scripts/.git/
fatal: failed to copy file to 'util_scripts/.git/objects/8f/c4e04df75c10422b3ebe2a5f1b1520da4eeb7c': Operation not permitted
```

If I try the same action in anywwere in my home directory all is well.

```
[cguest@devserver temp]$ pwd
/home/cguest/temp
[cguest@devserver temp]$  git clone  /home/cguest/repositories/util_scripts util_scripts
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/cguest/temp/util_scripts/.git/
[cguest@devserver temp]$
```

Here is some background information on the mounted partition.

```
[cguest@devserver groupmount]$ ls /mnt/ -lt 
total 1
drwxrwx--- 1 root devgroup    0 Feb 24 14:35 groupmount
[cguest@devserver temp]$ grep groupmount  /etc/mtab  
//srv01/groupmount /mnt/groupmount cifs rw 0 0
```

I suspect that I need to explain to `git` that it needs to use a specific umask when cloning to this partition. Although `/mnt/groupmount` is mounted as root, I have write permissions there by virtue of membership in the `devgroup` group.